# Package-by-layer VS package-by-feature library naming?

Tags: java, architecture, package

I know this has several associated posts, but I have some specific questions which I am hoping I can get help with. Sorry if they are very basic..

Here is a sample problem - very simplified, but you get the picture - I have several objects, which have some common function e.g. departments in a pharmaceutical company - neurology, oncology, infection etc. They all need to parse patient document files, and upload data to the database. Of course the nature of the data is slightly different for each department. If I used package-by-feature, I would have

```
com.company.neurology
      Neurology.java
      NeurologyDocument.java
      NeurologyDAO.java

com.company.infection
      Infection.java
      InfectionDocument.java
      InfectionDAO.java
```

etc.
The problem is that I need an abstract class that the Document classes need to extend e.g.

```
AbstractDocument.java
public class AbstractDocument
{
      public void validateDocument(){...}
      public void readDocumentHeader(){...}
      public void readDocumentFooter(){...}
       ...
}
```

Some data access files e.g.

```
DBConnection.java
    public class DBConnection
    {
        public void makeConnectionToDB() {... }
        public void createCache() {... }
        public void closeConnectionToDB() {... }
    }
```

some error classes

```
ParseError.java, PatientNotFoundException etc.
```

If packages are by feature, where do these common classes/interfaces go?

Comment: I guess one could do that, but there would be a bunch of very unrelated classes in such a 'common' package.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think in your case you should create some `common` package. I guess something is wrong with the abstractions used.

You must find a way to unite classes with the same purpose into some package and place this package under `com.company.shared.<feature_name>`.

In your case it could be:

- com.company.shared.database
- com.company.shared.data_parsing

It is no problem for a package to contain only one or two classes. But it should unite only classes with the same purpose and have a clear speaking name.

Avoid such names for both packages and classes as `common`. A name should talk for itself.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend keeping things simple. Provided you don't get lazy about it, putting them into `com.company` is a reasonable solution.

The caveat here is that this requires the discipline to move these out into separate packages whenever you notice groups of organizational commonality.

In the case of your example, you've already started to make these connections - your post itself is segmented to suggest these additional packages:

```
com.company.dataaccess
com.company.error
```

`AbstractDocument.java` probably doesn't merit it's own package - yet. If you end up creating more related interfaces / classes, then move them into an appropriate package, but don't borrow trouble by worrying about it until it actually becomes an issue.

Comment: If I created com.company.dataaccess and com.company.error, I would be extending code across packages(not recommended!). Also  com.company.dataaccess would not contain the DAO files as these would be in the individual department files. So related code is spread out. I guess there is no perfect design...

Comment: I think you are thinking of package as an OOP principle, rather than a Java package (which is more of a namespace). Extending across `jar` files is not recommended, but extending across packages is not necessarily bad design. That said, the error messages are probably better kept closer to the class that uses them. I had inferred, apparently incorrectly, that these would be error/exception types that would be used liberally throughout the application.

Comment: Hi , the errors would be used liberally, so you are right to talk of keeping it in a central location. I have been reading Bloch's 'Effective Java', which advocates keeping subclasses in the same package as the parent class, but obviously, one cannot obey every design principle all the time....